# Show that the matrix $AA^T+\alpha I$ is positive definite, where $\alpha >0$ and $A$ is an $m\times n$ real matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite

Show that the matrix $AA^T+\alpha I$ is positive definite, where $\alpha >0$ and $A$ is an $m\times n$ real matrix.

So I need to show that $x^T(AA^T+\alpha I)x>0$ for all vectors $x$. I'm really confused as to how to do this and how this is even true in general. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Is $AA^T$ positive semidefinite?  Also, the inequality should hold for all *nonzero* vectors $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure, it wasn't stated.

Comment: No, you misunderstand, $AA^T$ *is* positive semidefinite - I'm asking why that is true...

Comment: @DerpMagoo Think at what happens when $x\in \ker(A^T)$.

Comment: Is it because $AA^T$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
$$
x^T(AA^T+\alpha I)x=x^TAA^Tx+\alpha x^Tx=|A^Tx|^2+\alpha|x|^2.
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

1) Show that $AA^T$ is positive semidefinite using that $\langle Bx,x\rangle =\langle x,B^Tx\rangle$ and $\langle x,x\rangle =\|x\|^2_2$.

2) Show that $\alpha I$ is positive definite.

3) Show that the sum of positive definite and positive semidefinite matrices is positive definite.